# How to embed Comment on Custom Template in Drupal 8 Twig

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a content type named Project and I created a template for it `page--project.html.twig` I am new with Drupal and I want to include a comment box and comment list on this page but not sure what to do. I already added a comment field on my content type. I tried rendering it using `{{ node.field_comments }}` but I am getting error. How can I include a comment on a

Answer (score 1):

Because variable `node` is not available in template `page` so you have to get field comment, render it and then append it to your template by implementing `hook_preprocess_page`:

**<your_theme>.theme**

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function <your_theme>_preprocess_page(array &$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if (!empty($node)) {
    $variables['field_comment'] = $node->comment->view('full');
  }
}
```

**page--project.html.twig**

```
{{ field_comment }}
```